# Swift: Reset an instance

Tags: swift, class, init

I'm wondering what the best-practice way to reset the attributes of an object are in swift. In the example code below, I'm looking for a way to reset the attributes of an object **without** creating a new object.

I understand that it would be best to make a new object, since it has the same effect, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without creating a new object. Also, I know that I could reset each attribute one by one, but in a class with lots of attributes, this would be a cleaner way to do so.

Example code:

```
var pingPong: Game = Game()

class Game {

    var player1Score: Int
    var player2Score: Int

    init() {
        self.player1Score = 0
        self.player1Score = 0
    }

    func newGame() {
        init() //Code in question
    }

}
```

I've tried calling the class `init()` from the `newGame()` method, which throws an error. I've also tried calling `self.init()`, after which I get an error telling me to instead use `type(of: self).init()`, which throws yet another error `Constructing an object of class type 'pingPong' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer`.

How can I accomplish resetting the attributes of an object without creating a new object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a magic function that just resets all of the properties.

The first option is to reset all of the properties by hand:

```
class Game {

    var player1Score: Int = 0
    var player2Score: Int = 0

    init() {
        
    }
    
    func reset() {
        player1Score = 0
        player2Score = 0
    }

    func newGame() {
        reset()
        //continue other newGame functions
    }

}
```

If you had a lot of properties, though, this could get tedious. Instead, you could encapsulate your state into a value type (`struct`) and create a new instance when you're ready for a new game. That might look like this:

```
struct GameState {
    var player1Score = 0
    var player2Score = 0
}

class Game {

    var gameState : GameState

    init() {
        self.gameState = GameState()
    }

    func newGame() {
        self.gameState = GameState()
        //continue other newGame functions
    }

}
```

That way, your `Game` instance stays the same, but the state that it owns is reset.